# Why language is not changing with set_language url in Django?

Tags: django, django-i18n

I added django-user-language-middleware package but it only change language when I manually change it at admin or DB.

When I use set_language link, it doesn't update language.

Before adding that middleware, it was working without any problem but I need to save language for user.

The middleware order:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
     'user_language_middleware.UserLanguageMiddleware',
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a simple custom view that change language of current user